# In a Unity3D script an object created in the Update method is null everywhere else

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have created an object in the Update function and stored it in a global reference, but in the Loop it is always null.

```
//The variable foo is global so it should be accessible everywhere
Foo foo; 

void Start()
{
    //The Loop method is called every 0.5 seconds
    InvokeRepeating("Loop", 1f, 0.5f);
}

void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        foo=new Foo();
}

void Loop()
{
    if(foo==null)
        Debug.Log("foo is null");//foo is always null
    else
        Debug.Log("foo is not null");//this line is never executed
}
```

When I press the "Jump" button, the is the "Space" button, foo is created but in the Loop it is always null. Why?

Comment: Is your `Foo` a MonoBehaviour, by any chance? MonoBehaviours shouldn't be created with `new` keyword, and they have equality operator overriden exactly for special comparison with null logic.

Comment: Your script is ok , the problem must be on your foo constructor.

Comment: Yes it's a MonoBehaviour

Answer (score 1):

You can not use contructors with MonoBehaviours. Please, use `AddComponent` method to add `MonoBehaviour` to an existing object instead.

Also, be aware that `==` operator is overridden for Unity objects, and `a == null` can be true while the `a` reference is actually is not null. This is done for `Destroy` and `DestroyImmediate` methods to work, and can result in a lot of confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I think that I've found the answer here:

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-operator_eq.html

The answer is at the bottom of the page.

```
GameObject go = new GameObject(); 
Debug.Log (go == null); // false

Object obj = new Object();
Debug.Log (obj == null); // true
```

If you create a GameObject the object will be different from null. Meanwhile if you create a normal Object the object will always be null. So it has nothing to do with the Update function.

Comment: Important notice: this is `UnityEngine.Object` class and not the basic C# `System.Object` class.